# Can you configure tls level for <tenant>.b2clogin.com

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are using B2C as our identity server, and a Pen Test has noted the b2login.com endpoint accepts TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1. Our company policy is to use TLSv1.2. Can I configure the TLS level (and cipher) on .b2clogin.com

Comment: Can you talk about your test method?

Comment: The pen test uses the tool sslscan

sslscan -xml=log <b2c tenant>.b2clogin.com

Answer (score 0):

As per this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azuretls12/), Microsoft Azure recommends all customers complete migration towards solutions that support transport layer security (TLS) 1.2 and to make sure that TLS 1.2 is used by default.

Currently one cannot configure b2clogin.com to accept only TLS 1.2, Microsoft controls it.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that b2clogin.com accepts 1.0 and 1.1. (as well as 1.2) I want to configure it so it only accepts 1.2

Comment: It's been 2+ years.  Is this still not an option to restrict 1.0 and 1.1 for B2C?